# How can I use mod_rewrite for user profile redirection without redirecting all other site resources?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to mod_rewrite and designing with it so I'd like to know if this is the correct approach and if the rules are not written well.

My current goal is for my users to have the ability to access their profiles via *"www.mysite.com/profilename"* and access their data via *"www.mysite.com/profilename/path/to/data"*.  But, I need to, of course, be able to access site resources; images in img/, javascript in js/, etc.  Therefore I wrote the first rule to be able to get to all resources by prepending each request with *"site/"*.  Is this a recommended method?  Is there another way, perhaps more "pro", to achieve a similar feature?  I want simplicity for my users and me.

This is what I've written thus far.

```
# Circumvent redirecting to profile if prepended with 'site' #
RewriteRule ^site/(.+)$ $1 [QSA,L,NC]

# Redirect user to profile #
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ profile/?user=$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect to user profile plus extra data #
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ profile/?user=$1&datapath=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I just realized I could probably get rid of that second rule altogether.  I'll keep working on that.

Comment: Yep, looks like rewriting the third rule to `RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?(.*) profile/?user=$1&datapath=$2 [NC,L]` will work to completely replace the second rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
#maps urls starting with '/site/ to '/'
RewriteRule ^site/(.+)$ $1 [L]

# don't rewrite (sub-)requests starting with /profile, or /site
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Redirect to user profile plus extra data #
RewriteRule ([^/]+)(/(.+))?$ profile/?user=$1&datapath=$3 [NC,L]
```